# Best place to put re-usable code in an ASP.NET MVC control?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC control which has to do some work to format some information from the model.  This results in fairly complicated logic to build up the desired HTML.  I want to be able to re-use this code multiple times within the control.  Is there a way I can create a method (or something similar) within the control that would do this?  I know that I can create UI helper methods, but wouldn't these be visible to every control?

What is the best practice for create a helper method for an ASP.NET MVC control?  Thanks!

**Additional Info:**

We are using ASP.NET MVC 3, but I don't think we use Razor much, so it might not be an option.

Comment: What do you refer to when you talk about *`ASP.NET MVC control`*? Partial, helper, editor template, display template?

Comment: I think he means **Partial View**...

Comment: partial view is what I mean, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best place for encapsulating your complex UI reusable code is HtmlHelper extensions:

```
public static class MyHtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyReusableCode<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object stuff)
        {
            // do the work and return formatting, etc
        }
}
```

Usage (in partial view or full view):

```
Html.MyReusableCode(model => m.Stuff, myOtherStuff);
```

---

### UPDATE

OK, it seems this question is dead. Anyway, just to clarify more, if you look at the MVC itself, all common UI logic has been implemented as HtmlHelper extensions, such as `DropDownFor`, `DisplayFor`, `TextboxFor`, etc

Comment: how is this question dead?  So you are saying I can't place a method in a view/control?

Comment: Aliostad, thanks, but where would I put this HtmlHelper extension method if I want it to show up in a partial view?  Thanks.

Comment: You create a static class as I mentioned. If you create a strongly-typed partial view, you can use the helper by using `Html` property in your partial view. This is the power of extension methods so your new helper method suddenly becomes accessible in your code. Just remember you have to import the names of your Html Helper.

Answer (score 1):

Just try and keep in mind, encapsulation and loose coupling.
If you need a helper method that only the control needs, create (maybe a static) method that is private/protected to that control. If this method needs to be called from outside the control itself, you can expose a separate method, perhaps you would like to do some additional checks, then call the internal method. Something like `.Render()`

Comment: How would I build this method though within the control?

Comment: Create a model which has all of your complicated logic, and have it expose properties that can be consumed by a view which will then generate your Html.

Comment: No, it is not a good idea if you could, since it cannot be re-used.

Comment: Well it depends on what 'reuse' means. Because you can create two views that display the same model differently. You can also create a model that inherits, or decorates another model to consume (or reuse) the logic.

Comment: I would rather not have it in the model, as the model shouldn't care what the HTML would look like.  The model has a well defined structure, and we can have multiple ways of displaying it.  I simply have a view which has a lot of repetitive work that I would like to factor into a method within ONLY that view.

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I just don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Could you not create  _display_ or _editor_ for that 'repetitive work'? `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.RepetiviteWork, "PartialName")`

Comment: @Jay, I'm basically trying to accomplish the functionality that `@helper` provides in the Razor view engine, but I don't have Razor to use.  So what would be the next best way?

Comment: You can create an extension like Aliostad suggested, but if you do not have the HtmlHelper, then you can extend off of another object. This may be your model, or another object that will be available to your view, closely related to your model.